# What are sorting algorithms that does not break previous sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Imagine i have an array of elements with name and type. First i run a quicksort array by name. But then i want to run a sort by type, so in each type class elements will remain sorted by name. Quicksort is not doing that, it can reorder. And Bubble sort is too slow. What good algorithm should i use for that? And how it that property of sorting function is called? (that preserves order of same elements)

Comment: You're looking for a "stable" sorting algorithm.

Comment: And Quicksort is not a stable sort.  Mergesort is though.

Comment: Incidentally, if `type` is comparable you don't strictly need a stable sort - you can just use e.g. quicksort and write the compare function to also compare by `type` whenever the names are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This property is called *stable sort*. There are [several such algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts), [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is one of the most familiar out of them.

P.S. Another alternative is to use a single sort, but use a compound comparator, that first compares by the "primary" criteria (type in your case), and if types are equal, by "secondary" criteria (name in your case). This way, you will get the output sorted in the order you are expecting using a single sort.